# How to figure out the exact ruby version that jRuby is compatible with

Tags: ruby, jruby, compatibility, changelog

When updating jRuby, I'm always having a look at their release notes to figure out which ruby syntax I'm able to use. Quite recently, the [change logs](http://jruby.org/2016/05/27/jruby-9-1-2-0) just say *Ruby 2.x compatibility*. Is there a way or place to find out against which exact ruby version it is compatible? I.e. ruby 2.2 differs from 2.3 quite a lot. Why are they just writing *2.x*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a

```
jruby --version
```

two version identifiers are printed. The first one gives the jRuby version, and the second one gives the Ruby language version which this jRuby is based on.